# Akka HTTP Redirect Error

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am using Akka-HTTP. I have the following URI's

> /a
>
> /b

I will receive the HIT on `/a` URI and I have a condition when that condition will be fulfilled then I want to redirect to `/b` URI

If that condition is not fulfilled then I am returning BAD REQUEST

Now the issue is in Akka-HTTP redirect URI is of type Standard Route and I want to return HTTP Response due to this I am unable to run the code.

Can anyone tell me how to redirect with HTTP Response type in Akka-HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect from one URI to another in Akka-HTTP, We can use the same HTTP response type.

> HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect,
>             headers = headers.Location(Uri("URI/End Point of Akka-http to Redirect")) :: Nil,
>             entity = response)

This method will redirect the incoming request to the URI provided in the `Location` part of a header.

Thanks